# Rails user params only allows some certain attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller I have:

```
if params[:sort].nil?
  @sort = "created_at"
else
  @sort = params[:sort]
end
@konkurrencer = Konkurrencer.where("id NOT IN(?)", @clicked).order("#{@sort} DESC")
```

I like to add if `params[:sort]` is different from `"created_at"`, `"ratings"`, or `"rating"` then it should sort after `"created_at"`.

Comment: What is the question? You want to ignore `params[:sort]` unless it is one of those three values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `.order("#{@sort} DESC")` isn't a good idea when `@sort` is taken straight from params. It would be better to use `.order('? DESC', @sort)`.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

I'm not sure if I read your question correctly but I'm assuming you want `created_at` to be the default order with the other valid options being `ratings` and `rating`.

```
@order = case params[:sort]
when 'ratings'
  'ratings DESC'
when 'rating'
  'rating DESC'
else # anything else
  'created_at DESC'
end

@konkurrencer = Konkurrencer.where("id NOT IN(?)", @clicked).order(@order)
```